# 1and1 Cron not running the mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am trying to set up a cron job with my 1and1 hosting. If i write a simple php code, cron runs normal. But when include the database connection and run the code, it does not run.

The code is blow:

```
    <?php mail('email@gmail.com','At4U test cron','testing cron'); ?>

<?php
    define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once(__ROOT__.'/AT4U/extensions/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    include(__ROOT__.'/AT4U/core/functions/general.php');
    function db_connect() {

        $db_name    = '***************';
        $db_user    = '***************';
        $host       = '***************';
        $password   = '***************';

        // Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once 
        static $connection;

        // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
        if(!isset($connection)) {

            $connection = mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$password,$db_name);
        }

        // If connection was not successful, handle the error
        if($connection === false) {
            // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
            return mysqli_connect_error(); 
        }
        return $connection;
    }

    $con = db_connect();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $latest_blog = $row['title'];
        }
    }

    email('email@gmail.com','Latest Blog',$latest_blog); 
?>
```

As you can see, at the top of the page, i inserted a simple email function just to test if the cron works. I get the email every minute. But below this simple code, i wrote the database query and try sending email with the information from database, but it does not work.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Use a `try-catch` block in order to get an email with the exception....http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: `static $connection;` is this even valid?

Answer (score 0):

(I am assuming the program does work running in the regular environment?)

A cron job runs in a different environment than web jobs.
Some possible causes:

1. Maybe the datebase stuff IS working, but the email statement at the is not working. The  mail(..) statement at the beginning differs from the email(..) statement at the end. Try using the same mail(..) statement at the end.
2. Try mailing the `__ROOT__`constant. Is that what you expected?
3. The working dir is different. I always use the following line at the beginning of my CLI and cron jobs  (You might want to remove the .. part depending on your situation.):
   `chdir(realpath(__DIR__ . '/..'));`
4. On my server in case of CLI/cron jobs for instance the following environment variables are empty: DOCUMENT_ROOT, HTTP_HOST, SERVER_SOFTWARE   (maybe others too)
5. Are your included files compatible with running in CLI/cron environment?
6. It might even use an other php.ini.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Mail function differs because i wanted to see if a php  mail function and included php mailer function works. email() function is used for phpmailer and it works. I will also try your other suggestion